# Wordpress carousel won't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jquery carousel slider that has recently stopped working in Chrome. I am not sure but I think it happened with the most recent WP update. It does work in Chrome because I have it on a JS Fiddle page....http://jsfiddle.net/dwest/89zednzn/

```js
jQuery(function($) { 

  // settings
  var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
  var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
  var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
  var $time_between_slides = 3000; // 3 seconds

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );

});
```

```css
.slider {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
  <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Bobby_piano_SunnySL.jpg"/>
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Bobby_guitarSL.jpg" />
 </li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cher-sunny_SL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/BobbyHebbandBeatles-SL1.jpg"/>
</li>
  <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/1976_disco_Sunny_coverSL.jpg" />
 </li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sunny_cover3.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/hebb_cd_200x200.jpg" />
 </li>
<li>
 <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/hebb-ringo2-SL1.jpg" />
 </li>
<li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sunny_cover200x200.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/hebb_Japan_guitar200x200.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sunny_cover2.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/SUNNY-SHEET200x200.jpg" />
 </li>
  <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Mia-Colodne-SL1.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/lou_rawls_sheet_music-SL1.jpg" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SUNNY-ebay_SL11.jpg" />
 </li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Sunny_Japan_SL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Hebb-Dodger-stadiumSL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Bobby_guitar_autograph_SL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Sunny-sheetmusic-Hebb-SL1.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sunshine-headSL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Georgie-Fame-SunnySL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/face-of-bobbySL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sunny-BONEY-M-SL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sheet-musicSL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Sunny-pageSL1.jpg"/>
</li>
<li><img src="http://sunnythesong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/3-guitarsSL1.jpg"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

It does not work on the Wordpress page where it is supposed to...http://sunnythesong.com/

Comment: Have you tried changing your "wrapper" function to `(function($) { // Your JS here })(jQuery);`?

Answer (score 2):

It is failing on SunnyTheSong.com because "$" is undefined.  Specifically, this fails with a JS error saying $ is undefined:

```
$('.slider')
```

Change your ready logic from:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your JS here
})
```

To:

```
(function($) { 
    // Your JS here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should have a look at [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Also, jQuery is already "enqueued" by WordPress, by default. No need to include it again from the CDN.

Comment: Point taken, answer updated.  And like you commented after me, the wrapper function still needs updating.